# MS Access linked tables and forms

Tags: excel, forms, linked-list

All,

Thank you in advance for your help. I'm new to Access and VBA, so please bear with me if I'm asking a silly question. Within Access, I have created a linked table, "PEDB Table", to an Excel spreadsheet that is updated several times per day. I also created a form based on that linked table, "PEDB Form." The form includes several text/check boxes that are not included fields on the linked table, nor on the original Excel spreadsheet. I fill out the form, including fields auto-generated from the linked table and that I have checked/typed into. I then export that form to PDF and forward to my colleagues several times per day.

I need to retain the information that I input for each record. As it stands now, in the fields that I have added, they change the data for all records on the form, not just the record on which I am working. Is there a way for me to save each form as a new record on a local table, even if the form is based on a linked table?

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yes, you can. But if you're not experienced at this, it might be beyond your current abilities.  You are better off if you can add the fields to your excel file so when you make the changes, you save them back to the excel file.

Comment: Hi Steve - thanks for the reply. I'd love to give it a shot, if you'd like to let me know the steps. You'd be surprised at what I can figure out with a little information. :)

Comment: You may have a problem, depending on your version of office but this article gives you some workarounds: [KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/904953)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Steve! I was able to find a way to do what I wanted.

Comment: Please post any links to articles or specific code that helped you so that others can learn from what you've done.

Comment: I reorganized my linked spreadsheet in order to capture the data that is entered manually, and changed the linked table and form to incorporate those additional fields. Unfortunately, I did not find a way to do what I originally wanted (as listed above), but that's the way I reached the end result.